# Check if the list is empty on the first request in Paging 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

I'm trying to check if the first request came with the empty object, to display a layout indicating that it has no item.

My solution was to create an exception of my own. I would like to know if there is another better way. Because I looked in the documentation and found nothing.

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Item> {
    return try {
        val position = params.key ?: FIRST_PAGE_INDEX
        val response = api.getItem(position, params.loadSize, searchKey)
        val nextKey = response?.next
        val itemList = response?.itemList ?: emptyList()

        if (itemList.isNotEmpty()) {
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = itemList,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = if (nextKey == LAST_PAGE_INDEX) null else nextKey
            )
        } else {
            LoadResult.Error(EmptyListException())
        }

    } catch (exception: IOException) {
        LoadResult.Error(exception)
    } catch (exception: HttpException) {
        LoadResult.Error(exception)
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461572/6893685

Answer (score 36):

To show EmptyView you can look `loadState.append` which represents the load state for loading data at the end of the list and can confirm
if there is no more data to load using `endOfPaginationReached` and after that can check `itemCout` of `PagingDataAdapter`. ` .

```
eg:  adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->

            if ( loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached )
            {
               if ( adapter.itemCount < 1)
                    /// show empty view
               else 
                   ///  hide empty view
            }
           }
```

Comment: Great solution! It works even better if you change it to `if (loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading &&
loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached)` because then you can set the empty view back to invisible when a new search is triggered